# How to use find and replace in excel sheet using wildcards?

Tags: excel, search, replace, wildcard

I have a big excel worksheet.
where in I have 100's of string matching the pattern -
`vrf*interface="string"`

I am putting here one of the instance matching that pattern -
`/native/router/eigrp/named-mode[name="eigrp"]/af-ipv4-vrf[vrf="abc"]/interface="genericstring"`

I want to replace the above string to -
`/native/router/eigrp/named-mode[name="eigrp"]/af-ipv4-vrf[vrf="abc"]/interface="xyz"`

So how can I achieve this in excel sheet search?

I use `vrf*interface="string"` as a search pattern it finds properly but when I perform a replace operation `vrf*interface="xyz"`-
`/native/router/eigrp/named-mode[name="eigrp"]/af-ipv4-vrf*interface="xyz"`

So how can i achieve the desired result here?

Comment: Do you want a VBA solution, or only normal Excel use?

Comment: Normal Excel use. I've zero knowledge on VB script.

Comment: @DarshanL Did you try `SUBSTITUTE()` function?

Comment: No, I've not tried it.

Comment: You need to match the entire string. `vrf*interface="string"` will only match (and replace) that part of the string starting with `vrf`.  To match the entire string, use `*vrf*interface="string"*`

Comment: Matching is happening with my current wildcard itself. But replacement is not working

Comment: @Harun24HR how to use `SUBSTITUTE` function?